# Netlify CMS - Uploadcare - Missing External Media Library

Tags: netlify, netlify-cms, uploadcare

My website deploys correctly but whenever I try to access my Netlify CMS admin panel I get this error:

```
Error loading the CMS configuration

Config Errors:

Error: Missing external media library ‘uploadcare’. Please use ‘registerMediaLibrary’ to register it.

Check your config.yml file.
```

Here is my config.yml file: https://pastebin.com/raw/gHzhvTGG

Here is my cms.js file: https://pastebin.com/raw/wMGtkKwm

Uploadcare has been registered and it has a valid api key. It was working fine previously.

I am running out of things to try

Comment: Are you using Gatsby? If so, you need to provide the path to your CMS customization entry point. See https://www.netlifycms.org/blog/2019/07/netlify-cms-gatsby-plugin-4-0-0#with-gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms400

Comment: @AlexChernenko Hi thanks for your reply! I already have the path to the cms in the gatsby-config file. Is there anything else that could be causing this?

Comment: Your config looks correct. I can only recommend that you open an issue for the template developers https://github.com/netlify-templates/gatsby-starter-netlify-cms/issues

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this?